# Remove an event category from a single event?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, categories, microsoft-graph-calendar

I'm trying to use MS Graph to modify an event in my (Office 365) Outlook calendar such that it comes to have zero categories. [Microsoft's "Update event" document](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events/) doesn't seem to tell how I can do this.

**Context:**
I have an event with the "Foo" category already assigned.

**Desired State:**
For the event to have no category assigned at all.

**What Has Worked**:
I have successfully *added* a category to the event by specifying an array with a single string that is the display name of the category, like so:

```
URI: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events/<id>
Method: PATCH
Body:
{
  "categories": ["Foo"]
}
```

**What Hasn't Worked:**
Setting "categories" to either an empty array (`[]`) or an array containing a single empty string (`[""]`) does not remove the category and does not return any error. Setting "categories" to `null` or `[null]` returns an error.

How can I modify an event to remove its category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a Patch works okay for me

```html
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/AAMk...TTP/1.1
Host: graph.microsoft.com

{"categories":[]}
```

When you try this what do you see in the response ? are you seeing the categories set back to []. If you do but you don't see the change in the client it may just be related to sync time (eg Outlook in Cache mode etc).

Are you using any of the SDK's to do the update it maybe a bug or issue with those libraries when you have a null or empty value but you need to specify more what SDK or library your using.

Comment: Outlook caching was in play - OWA reflects changes with no caching (ty!!). Even still, Graph API (I'm calling from Power Automate's "Send an HTTP Request"), when given the empty array, sometimes returns empty array for "categories" and sometimes returns the pre-call "categories" value (["Foo"], unchanged). Very strange. I'm marking this as answered, as "empty array" _is_ the "clear the categories" syntax (the Outlook caching is to blame for my initial confusion). If there's some bug or other user error that makes Graph API sometimes mismanage/ignore the input, we can address that elsewhere.

Comment: No there is conflict resolution that can happen at the server level EWS used to let you set that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.conflictresolutionmode?view=exchange-ews-api. Exchange has good calendar diagnostics and has a folder that tracks changes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-calendardiagnosticobjects?view=exchange-ps maybe able to help see what is happening